# MapContainer in InteractionDialog showing in simulator but not on Android

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

In my app I resort to MapContainer twice. The first time in a form and the second time in an InteractionDialog launched from another form.

In the simulator the map appears :

[image: Map appearing in the simulator]

but on a real device it doesn't :

[image: Map not appearing on the device]

Is it possible indeed to add a MapContainer in the centre of an InteractionDialog (in BorderLayout) ? If so how can I do that ?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: Your question is a bit vague without code snippets and screenshots.

Comment: @Diamond : screenshots added! Yet Shai found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred size of a `MapContainer` might be 0 on the device and as a result you would see nothing. If you explicitly set the preferred size this might work. However, we haven't tested that use case.

Comment: You're right, I did notice the narrow blue line representing the Map while watching the screen capture of the device! Thanks Shai!